# How do I get the Date & Time (VBS)

Tags: vbscript

How do I get the current date and time using VBS (for Windows. I'm not looking for VBScript for ASP/ASPX or webpages).

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_date.asp

Comment: asawyer thats for webpages. Not seeking webpages. Even if your answer was correct, I can't give you credit because you added it as a comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To expound on Numenor's answer you can do something like, [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bz1f0h%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)(Now(),"HH:mm:ss") 
using these [custom date/time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73ctwf33%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) formating options

---

For everyone who is tempted to downvote this answer please be aware that the question was originally tagged VB and vbscript hence my answer, the VB tag was edited out leaving only the vbscript tag. The OP **accepted** this answer which I take to mean that it gave him the information that he needed.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner You seem to have missed the Vb tag that Joel Coehoorn edited out on Feb 27. This question was originally tagged Vb and VBScript hence the answer that I gave, and it seemed to meet the OP's requirements since he marked it as the answer.

Comment: I just want the answer to be correct for the question as it is now. I shouldn't have down voted, my apologies.

Answer (score 61):

Here's various date and time information you can pull in *vbscript* running under Windows Script Host (WSH):

```
Now   = 2/29/2016 1:02:03 PM
Date  = 2/29/2016
Time  = 1:02:03 PM
Timer = 78826.31     ' seconds since midnight

FormatDateTime(Now)                = 2/29/2016 1:02:03 PM
FormatDateTime(Now, vbGeneralDate) = 2/29/2016 1:02:03 PM
FormatDateTime(Now, vbLongDate)    = Monday, February 29, 2016
FormatDateTime(Now, vbShortDate)   = 2/29/2016
FormatDateTime(Now, vbLongTime)    = 1:02:03 PM
FormatDateTime(Now, vbShortTime)   = 13:02

Year(Now)   = 2016
Month(Now)  = 2
Day(Now)    = 29
Hour(Now)   = 13
Minute(Now) = 2
Second(Now) = 3

Year(Date)   = 2016
Month(Date)  = 2
Day(Date)    = 29

Hour(Time)   = 13
Minute(Time) = 2
Second(Time) = 3

Function LPad (str, pad, length)
    LPad = String(length - Len(str), pad) & str
End Function

LPad(Month(Date), "0", 2)    = 02
LPad(Day(Date), "0", 2)      = 29
LPad(Hour(Time), "0", 2)     = 13
LPad(Minute(Time), "0", 2)   = 02
LPad(Second(Time), "0", 2)   = 03

Weekday(Now)                     = 2
WeekdayName(Weekday(Now), True)  = Mon
WeekdayName(Weekday(Now), False) = Monday
WeekdayName(Weekday(Now))        = Monday

MonthName(Month(Now), True)  = Feb
MonthName(Month(Now), False) = February
MonthName(Month(Now))        = February

Set os = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_OperatingSystem=@")
os.LocalDateTime = 20131204215346.562000-300
Left(os.LocalDateTime, 4)    = 2013 ' year
Mid(os.LocalDateTime, 5, 2)  = 12   ' month
Mid(os.LocalDateTime, 7, 2)  = 04   ' day
Mid(os.LocalDateTime, 9, 2)  = 21   ' hour
Mid(os.LocalDateTime, 11, 2) = 53   ' minute
Mid(os.LocalDateTime, 13, 2) = 46   ' second

Dim wmi : Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
Set timeZones = wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT Bias, Caption FROM Win32_TimeZone")
For Each tz In timeZones
    tz.Bias    = -300
    tz.Caption = (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
Next
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/mkropat/7799532)

Comment: Should be the "new" accepted answer for this question

Answer (score 8):

For VBScript use FormatDateTime, which has 5 numerical arguments to give you one of 5 predefined formats.  Its not great.

```
  FormatDateTime(now, 4)
  08:12
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but alot of the answers in here use VB or VBA. The tag says vbscript (which is how I got here).

The answers here got kind of muddled since VB is super broad where you can have so many applications of it. My answer is solely on vbscript and accomplishes my case of **formatting in YYYYMMDD in vbscript**

Sharing what I've learned:

1. There are all the `DateTime` functions in vbscript defined [here](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_vbscript_functions.asp) so you can mix-n-match to get the result that you want
2. What I needed was to get the current date and format it in `YYYYMMDD` to do that I just needed to concat `DatePart` like so for the current Date: `date = DatePart("yyyy",Date) & DatePart("m",Date) & DatePart("d",Date)`

That's all, I hope this helps someone.

Comment: However DatePart doesn't return leading "0", see example given on https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_datepart.asp : `d=CDate("2010-02-16")
DatePart("m",d)` returns 2 not 02. So you have to pad like in this answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52822934/666414

Answer (score 2):

Show time in form 24 hours

```
Right("0" & hour(now),2) & ":" & Right("0" & minute(now),2)   = 01:35
Right("0" & hour(now),2)                                      = 01
Right("0" & minute(now),2)                                    = 35
```

Answer (score 1):

`now`returns the current date and time

Comment: Can I manipulate the returned string? for example. I want to have the time in 24 hour format (no AM/PM)

Answer (score 1):

There are also separate `Time()` and `Date()` functions.