# wix SetProperty Before='AppSearch'

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

How i can change date and time format? I need replace ":" to "_" in time.
Below my code:

```
<SetProperty Before='AppSearch' Sequence='both' Id='HOSTNAME' Value="[ComputerName]_[Time]_[Date]">NOT HOSTNAME</SetProperty>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The MSI SDK** documents this pretty well: [Time Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/time):

*The format of the value depends upon the user's locale, and is the format obtained using **GetTimeFormat** function with the `TIME_FORCE24HOURFORMAT | TIME_NOTIMEMARKER` option.*

So the user's locale will affect the format, and then you probably need to use a custom action to get the formatting the way you want it. I can't think of any other way to do it.

***All time silliest VBScript***: (it is very late)

```
MsgBox Day(Now) & "_" & Month(Now) & "_" & Year(Now) & "_" & Hour(Now) & "_" & Minute(Now) & "_" & Second(Now)
```

And just a hint for how to insert custom actions can be found here: [How to execute conditional custom action on install and modify only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370505/how-to-execute-conditional-custom-action-on-install-and-modify-only/52377800#52377800)

---

- https://ss64.com/vb/syntax-getdatetime.html
- https://ss64.com/vb/syntax-getdate.html
- https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_vbscript_functions.asp
- [How do I get the Date & Time (VBS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011357/how-do-i-get-the-date-time-vbs/19939013#19939013)

Comment: Added a link above on how to use custom actions in your package. Also [see this answer for WiX sample links and how-to tips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130).

Comment: Like this? - 


     `<Binary Id='datetime.vbs' SourceFile='datetime.vbs' />`
     `<CustomAction Id='datetime.vbs' VBScriptCall='' BinaryKey='datetime.vbs' Execute='immediate' Return='ignore' />`
     `<SetProperty Before='AppSearch' Sequence='both' Id='HOSTNAME' Value="datetime">NOT HOSTNAME</SetProperty>`

Comment: Can't test this right now, and hard to tell without knowing more about what you need to do, but you need to use a regular custom action element inserted into the `InstallExecuteSequence` and the `InstallUISequence` and not just a SetProperty element. [See here, bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52377800/129130). If it does not run, then there is an error in the script. [Check the MSI log](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm). Try to create a dummy VBScript that does nothing that can go wrong: `MsgBox "Hello!"` to see if you have a "heartbeat".

Comment: It is always wrong to use a custom action if you do not need them. [Here is a description of why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179778/why-is-it-a-good-idea-to-limit-the-use-of-custom-actions-in-my-wix-msi-setups/46179779#46179779). If you can avoid them, please do so. However, sometimes they are unavoidable. [VBScript custom actions are particularly frowned upon](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2005/02/07/dont-use-vbscriptjscript-to-write-your-custom-actions/), but can help avoid dependencies on the .NET framework for trivial operations (such as just setting a property).